# send a swiftyjson array using moya

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json, moya

I'm trying to send a swiftyJSON array of json objects using moya but it keeps producing an error and crashing.

My task is as follows:

```
case let .example(token, json):
    return .requestParameters(parameters: ["token": token, "choices": json!.array as Any], encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
```

Where token is just a string and json is of type JSON.

The error is:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (_SwiftValue)'

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Whats the error and on what line? Please give more details

Comment: @Skywalker added the error in the question. Doesn't show on what line - but the same call works when just using strings or arrays, but not when using SwiftyJSON objects.

Answer (score 2):

```
case let .example(token, json):
  var parameters: [String : Any] = [:]
  parameters["token"] = token
  parameters["choices"] = products.map({
      key, value in
      return [ "product_id": key, "qty": value ]
  })
  return .requestParameters(parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.prettyPrinted)
```